# PostgreSQL: UPDATE large table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, geometry, postgis

I have a large PostgreSQL table of 29 million rows. The size (according to the stats tab in pgAdmin is almost 9GB.) The table is post-gis enabled with an empty geometry column.

I want to UPDATE the geometry column using ST_GeomFromText, reading from X and Y coordinate columns (SRID: 27700) stored in the same table. However, running this query on the whole table at once results in 'out of disk space' and 'connection to server lost' errors... the latter being less frequent.

To overcome this, should I UPDATE the 29 million rows in batches/stages? How can I do 1 million rows (the FIRST 1 million), then do the next 1 million rows until I reach 29 million?

Or are there other more efficient ways of updating large tables like this?

I should add, the table is hosted in AWS.

My UPDATE query is:

```
UPDATE schema.table
SET geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || eastingcolumn || ' ' || northingcolumn || ')',27700);
```

Comment: try perform the updated  for a limit set of rows .. if you have in id for each row the first  100.000 first the try for sets of 1M

Comment: Can't help on the disk space issue, but st_point is quicker than st_geomfromtext https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/st-makepoint-or-st-pointfromtext-to-generate-points

Comment: @mlinth do you mean ST_MakePoint or ST_PointFromText? Or actually ST_Point? Sorry, just clarifying.

Comment: st_point. As the link explains, st_pointfromtext uses st_geomfromtext under the hood.

Comment: @mlinth thanks. Can you help me with the syntax for st_point? I can't get it working, even using https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html

Comment: ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(eastingcolumn,northingcolumn),27700); Your columns need to be floats (or casted to floats if they are text eg eastingcolumn::numeric).

Comment: @mlinth thanks. That worked. My X Y columns were bigint types though, not floats. (Or are they the same thing?). Would it work if my X Y columns were DOUBLE PRECISION types?

Comment: Yes - should work, and the casting would be implicit. More info on casts here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my original question:

> However, running this query on the whole table at once results in 'out of disk space' and 'connection to server lost' errors... the latter being less frequent.

Turns out our Amazon AWS instance database was running out of space, stopping my original ST_GeomFromText query from completing. Freeing up space fixed it.

On an important note, as suggested by @mlinth, ST_Point ran my query far quicker than ST_GeomFromText (24mins vs 2hours).

My final query being:

```
UPDATE schema.tablename
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(eastingcolumn,northingcolumn),27700);
```

Answer (score 8):

You did not give any server specs, writing 9GB can be pretty fast on recent hardware.

You should be OK with one, long, update - **unless** you have concurrent writes to this table.

A common trick to overcome this problem (a very long transaction, locking writes to the table) is to split the UPDATE into ranges based on the primary key, ran in separate transactions.

```
/* Use PK or any attribute with a known distribution pattern */
UPDATE schema.table SET ... WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000;
UPDATE schema.table SET ... WHERE id BETWEEN 1000001 AND 2000000;
```

For high level of concurrent writes people use more subtle tricks (like: SELECT FOR UPDATE / NOWAIT, lightweight locks, retry logic, etc).

Comment: thanks for the response, however my table doesn't have an id column that increments 1, 2, 3, .... 29000000 etc. My primary key column is a uprn (a unique reference number between 1 and 12 digits long). In short, I don't know what the distribution pattern is.

Comment: EDIT: I've added an ID column using- ALTER TABLE schema.tablename ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;

Comment: taking a test table of 1 million rows, UPDATE 'ing one column for the whole table at once took 1 minute. UPDATE 'ing the same column in this table in 4 parts WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 250000 etc etc, takes 47 seconds just for one of the 4 parts. so in total we can assume it'd take around 3 minutes for the whole table...

Comment: @TheoF thanks for adding some detail :-) it proves that maybe splitting update in batches is not worth the extra complexity, and choosing "the best" solution depends on environment.